# Returning a message back from SQL Server Stored Procedure to C# BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures, backgroundworker

I am using a bacgroundworker in my C# Winforms app to call a stored procedure in SQL Server. The reason I am doing this is that I am using raiserror messages to send back rows counts and messages to a progress bar that shows the progress of the stored procedure. That all works fine. My problem is at the end of the stored procedure I have a message that returns a success message. The success message is declared an an output parameter in the stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @returnMessage   OUTPUT
```

Then I say something like:

```
SET @returnMessage = "Posting dues has successfully completed on ' + GetDate()
```

Now in my app, I have my DoWork method where I connect and execute my stored procedure. Here is the pertinent code:

```
conn.InfoMessage += (o, args) => self.ReportProgress(0, args.Message);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ua_sp_PostPeriodicDues", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@periodCode", periodCode));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nextPostingDate", nextPostingDate));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@repost", repost));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@localFieldName", localFieldName));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userCd", userCd));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@runNow", runNow));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@returnMessage", returnMessage)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
returnMessage = cmd.Parameters["@returnMessage"].Value.ToString();
```

returnMessage is a string that is defined at the class level so it is available to the RunWorkerCompleted method.

In my RunWorkerCompleted method I have the following lines.

```
form.Kill();                    //closes progress bar modeless dialog
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
MessageBox.Show(returnMessage); //display the success
```

Problem is the returnMessage variable always returns an empty string. I am just using an output parameter in the stored procedure with no return. Does my output parameter have to be handled differently on the C# side because it is in a backgroundworker?  Is there a better way to return back a success at the end of the stored procedure. Is doing with a backgroundworker causing the problem?

Comment: `DECLARE @returnMessage   OUTPUT` does this cause a problem on the Sql Server.. have you tested this outside of C#..? you didn't declare a Datatype for the returnMessage also please show all relevant code show what the stored procedure looks like

Comment: sorry i mistyped the returnMessage is declared as a varchar(100)  OUTPUT. The stored procedure runs fine in SQL Server manager. The only thing i cant get back from the SP is the returnMessage. It comes back an empty string

Comment: no problem.. sometimes it's easier to break down. there are many ways to skin this cat.. I hope that my answer provided you a fix as well as a different way of looking at the same issue and or problem yet yielding the proper results..

Answer (score 1):

I would break it down and add the Output Paramter and declare the datatype as well as follows:

```
SqlParameter returnMessage = new SqlParameter("@returnMessage", SqlDbType.String);
returnMessage.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add(returnMessage);  
cmd.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
var result = returnParameter.Value;
```

-Please change this code

`SET @returnMessage = 'Posting dues has successfully completed on ' + GetDate()`

to

```
SET @returnMessage = 'Posting dues has successfully completed on ' + GetDate()
```

Comment: I still can't get a message returned back from the stored procedure. the parameter returns back as an empty string

Comment: I am able to test this on my side creating a generic sql statement and stored proc.. you must be doing something wrong..you stated that it was a typo on your param.. please edit you question and post all real code changes that you are trying to execute..

Comment: could the problem be that on the c# side i am executing the stored procedure in a backgroundworker. Does that affect the way the message comes back?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @returnMessage VARCHAR(100)  OUTPUT
```

is not valid TSQL.  This should return an error.

OUTPUT parameters have to be actual parameters of the stored procedure.  You can't declare them inside the procedure scope and try to return them from there.

Make the output parameter part of the SP definition and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You say it's working in the SQL Server query analyzer, but not in (I assume) production. The likely culprit is a schema issue. You are referencing your stored procedure without schema-qualifying the name. Reference to SQL objects that are not schame-qualified are looked up in the following manner:

- First the current connection's default schema is probed for an object matching the referenced name. If found, the reference is resolved. Otherwise...
- The `dbo` schema is probed for an object matching the referenced name.

It is possible to have multiple objects of the same name that are owned by different schemas, with the result that different logins (attached to different default schemas) can (and will) resolve such unqualified references differently. With the odd results you seem to be seeing.

Unless you have a very good reason not to do so, **always schema-qualify your object references and SQL `create` statements.**

That being said, given this stored procedure:

```
create procedure dbo.mySproc
  @p1 varchar(32) ,
  @p2 varchar(8000) output
as

  set @p2 = case
              when @p1 is null then 'Hello, <null>!'
              else                  'Hello, ' + @p1
            end
  return 0
go
```

This code should do you:

```
using ( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectString) )
using(  SqlCommand cmd =  connection.CreateCommand() )
{
  cmd.CommandText = "dbo.mySproc" ;
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;

  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@p1" , "Emily" ) ;

  cmd.Parameters.Add( "@p2" , SqlDbType.VarChar , 8000 );
  cmd.Parameters["@p2"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output ;

  connection.Open();
  int rc = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  connection.Close();

  string message = (string) cmd.Parameters["@p2"].Value ;
  Console.WriteLine( "The message is: {0}",message);

}
```

And should produce

```
The message is: Hello, Emily
```

Comment: No the stored procedure is working in the production environment. the stored procedure runs properly and it returns raiserror methods to the progress changed method. the only thing that is not working is the output message. it is an empty string. now looking at your example do i have to close the connection before i can access the output parameter. also does it make a difference that the stored procedure is executed from within a doworker method? even though the SP is fired off asynchronously does the statement that grabs the output parameter only get populated when the SP is completed.

Comment: You shouldn't have to close the connection. SQL connections are cached by default and not actually closed. All the close() does is return the open connection to the connection pool so it's availabled for reuse. It's just good practice to open the connection, execute your command and close the connection so as to minimize your use of the shared resource.